# Javascript - deepEqual Comparison and Recursion

Tags: javascript, function, loops, recursion

I'm teaching myself JavaScript, and I'm stuck on the following problem from *Eloquent JavaScript*:

> Write a function, deepEqual, that takes two values and returns true
>   only if they are the same value or are objects with the same
>   properties whose values are also equal when compared with a recursive
>   call to deepEqual. To find out whether to compare two things by
>   identity (use the === operator for that) or by looking at their
>   properties, you can use the typeof operator. If it produces "object"
>   for both values, you should do a deep comparison. But you have to take
>   one silly exception into account: by a historical accident, typeof
>   null also produces "object".

My question:
Why does `console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}))` come out as false when `a[key]` is `{ is: 'an' }` and `b[key]` is `{ is: 'an' }`  but true when that code is substituted with `!deepEqual(a[key], b[key])`?

The code:

```
function deepEqual(a, b){
    if (a === b) {
        return true;
    } 
    else if (typeof a== typeof b && !(a===null ||b===null)){
        for(var key in b){
            for(key in a){
                if(! (key in a)){
                    return false;
                } 
                else if (a[key] !== b[key]){
                    return false;
                }
                else 
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
  else
      return false;
}

var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
```

Comment: You miss the part "recursive call to deepEqual". Answer is in the question. :)  What's `obj` ?

Comment: I am confused about why `(a[key] !== b[key])`  isn't doing the same thing that the recursive function would have done. (I'm trying to solve the problem non-recursively as well.) I've edited the question to reflect the obj variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because `a[key]` and `b[key]` are both Objects, you need to use `deepEquals` on them as well.

Currently, you're not calling `deepEquals` recursively, so there's no way that will happen.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how the recursive function works here now. But what would I need to do in order to solve the problem non-recursively? If a & b are objects, we can check whether `a===b`. If `a[key]` and `b[key]` are also objects, how come we can't check whether `a[key] !== b[key]` ?